# Formatting Data from Hashie

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you format the data output from a call to twitter (for example). My output's in the following format:

```
<#Hashie::Mashcontributors=nil coordinates=nil created_at="Wed May 04 18:57:32 +0000 2011" favorited=false geo=nil id=65852579048980480 id_str="65852579048980480" in_reply_to_screen_name=nil in_reply_to_status_id=nil in_reply_to_status_id_str=nil in_reply_to_user_id=nil in_reply_to_user_id_str=nil place=nil retweet_count=0 retweeted=false source="web" text="what's happening?" truncated=false user=<#Hashie::Mash contributors_enabled=false created_at="Wed May 04 09:17:26 +0000 2011" default_profile=true default_profile_image=true description=nil favourites_count=0 follow_request_sent=false followers_count=0 following=false friends_count=0 geo_enabled=false id=292829579 id_str="292829579" is_translator=false lang="en" listed_count=0 location=nil name="PSTest" notifications=false profile_background_color="C0DEED" profile_background_image_url="http://a3.twimg.com/a/1304436748/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" profile_background_tile=false profile_image_url="http://a1.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png" profile_link_color="0084B4" profile_sidebar_border_color="C0DEED" profile_sidebar_fill_color="DDEEF6" profile_text_color="333333" profile_use_background_image=true protected=false screen_name="PSTest4" show_all_inline_media=false statuses_count=8 time_zone=nil url=nil utc_offset=nil verified=false>>
```

As a newbie, this just looks like junk to me!! I'm trying to display the latest 10 tweets from users on my app. Just don't know how to get started...

B

== edit ==

In order to display the text only, I've now tried the following.

```
<%= @user.twitter_token.timeline.each do |t| %>
<%= t.text %>
<% end %>
```

Although I get no errors, I can see the correct output but there hash still lingers after the output. Not sure why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hashie lets you access things using dot notation (e.g. `@tweet.created_at` instead of `@tweet["created_at"]`.

So assuming the object you posted is `@tweet`, you could do this:

```
@tweet.coordinates
# => nil
@tweet.user.name
# => "PSTest"
@tweet.text
# => "what's happening?"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If my user model contains: @timeline = client.home_timeline. Should I call this plus the .coordiates in my view?

Comment: It `client.home_timeline` returns the `Hashie::Mash` object you posted, then yes, `@timeline.coordinates` would give you that value.

Comment: Great, I can get the first tweet out using that. How can I create a loop to list the last 10 tweets? Probably need a tutorial but don't know what to search for. Cheers

Comment: PS. Have added my first attempt to initial question. Many thanks again.